# Importing from Excel / Excel Linked Server shows no data

Tags: excel, ms-access, ssis, linked-server, jet

This is a common problem I've had for years and I'm sure many others have experienced.  Every time I search, I don't seem to get exactly what I'm needing, so I figure I'd just ask to see if anyone has an answer or at least point me to the place with the right answer.

The scenario is commonly I'll have an excel workbook that has not been opened yet, typically an export from a BusinessObjects datamart, but not limited to just that source.  Anyway, any time I've tried to import the workbook into Access, create a linked server in SQL server, or even use the workbook as an Excel Source in SSIS, the worksheet comes through with no data even though it has data.  However, if I were to open the file manually in Excel, save it and close, all of the above show the data as expected.  This is a very frustrating problem that I have yet to find a more automated solution to other than having some clunky script open the workbook in an excel instance, save it, then close it again.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are there any version differences(xls vs xlsx, etc.)? Excel is a special kind of headache for doing ETL.

Comment: The source excel workbook is almost always xls, given that our version of BusinessObjects still exports to a 97-2003 version of Excel. As far as destination versions, I've had this problem in Access 2000 & 2007 and SQL Server 2005.